# Extracting pattern from an equation

Tags: formatting

I have for example the following eqn
$
j(\text{tl},0,1,1,0,0,0,1)'(s)+\frac{(d-4) j(\text{tl},0,1,1,0,0,0,1)}{2 s}
$
I want to find out the pattern with the prime or the derivative, in this case `j(tl,0,1,1,0,0,0,1)`. How to do in mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Cases[j[tl, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]'[s] +
    (d \[Minus] 4) j[tl, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]/2 s, Derivative[_][_][_] ]

       {Derivative[1][j[tl, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]][s]}
```

Comment: `Cases[j[tl, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]'[ s] + (d \[Minus] 4) j[tl, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]/2 s, f_'[__]]` results in `{Derivative[1][j[tl, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]][s]}`